# Transfer WhatsApp ICloud Backup to Android? (or PC)

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, android, whatsapp.app

I'm swapping back to Android, and I am curious if I can somehow access my WhatsApp Backup in the iCloud or on the Phone itself.

I know there is a Function for that now in Android, but for that, you have to wipe your phone.

I tried the methods that were posted a while ago (Mobile Documents -> WhatsApp)

But in there are just 2 Folders that are empty.

Would be great about any help. Pretty sure, when Paid Tools can do it, we can just manually do it as well :)